# Simple variable issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change my variables inside my items variable and not sure how to do it.

```
var items = [
            {name: '#builder', x: 0, y:15},
            {name: '#image', x: 0, y:15},
            {name: '#button', x: -100, y: -55}

          ];

    //I only want to change builder and image but not button...How to do this?

          if(i>5){
            items = [
            {name: '#builder', x: 50, y:105},
            {name: '#image', x: 110, y:115}            

          ];

          }
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using an object hash table instead?

```
var items = {
        '#builder' : { x: 0, y:15},
        '#image': { x: 0, y:15},
        '#button': {x: -100, y: -55}
        };
```

Then you can change them like so:

```
items['#builder'].x = 50;
```

If it's not an option, that's cool, but it seems like if you want to look things up by name, this might be a better route for you.

Outside of that, you'd have to loop through each record to find the name you wanted and set the values appropriately.

```
var items = [
            {name: '#builder', x: 0, y:15},
            {name: '#image', x: 0, y:15},
            {name: '#button', x: -100, y: -55}
          ];

function updateValues(name, x, y) {
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
         var item = items[i];
         if(item.name == name) {
             item.x = x;
             item.y = y;
             return;
         }
    }
}


updateValues('#builder', 50, 105);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the position, then you could do:

```
if (i > 5) {
  items[0].x = 50;
  items[0].y = 105;
  items[1].x = 110;
  items[1].y = 115;
}
```